# How to call JOptionPane with only Yes/No options?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Is it possible to call a confirmation dialog, that would have ONLY `YES` and `NO` options (without the CANCEL option)?

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure?")
```

Gives three options, but I need only two.

Comment: Not a dupe -- that question is about setting the options arbitrarily, which would be overkill here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. it is possible.

```
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
   "Are you sure you wish to exit application?",null, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if(result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Rather then using a "magic number" could use the constant `JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION` instead. Not only is it more readable, if, for some reason, the constant changes, it won't break your code

Answer (score 3):

Try using the other Overload method of [JOption.showConfirmDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) method. that takes `optionType`. You can pass `YES_NO_OPTION`, `YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION`, or `OK_CANCEL_OPTION` option types.

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure?", "Message",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the other [`showConfirmDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) where you can specify the `optionType`.

#### E.G.

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Test", "Test1", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

From the docs:-

> Brings up a dialog where the number of choices is determined by the optionType parameter.

Comment: No, providing 2 will display OK_CANCEL_OPTION. You should be using 0 or more better use the constants provided in same class.

Comment: Rather then using a "magic number" could use the constant `JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION` instead.  Not only is it more readable, if, for some reason, the constant changes, it won't break your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure question?", "titleToYouMessageBox", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);